# Error loading Turtle File in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am attempting to load a Turtle file into Android studio and use the Androjena library to run queries against the Turtle file. I am able to do this in Eclipse with JavaFX with no issue. However, in the Intellij IDE I am getting a FATAL error which obviously crashes my app. I have a method called runQuery() that is called in order to run a query on the File:

```
public String runQuery(){
             String stringQuery = "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> \n" +
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> \n" +
            "SELECT ?birthDate WHERE { \n" +
            "?barack foaf:name \"Barack Obama\"@en .\n" +
            "?barack dbo:birthDate ?birthDate \n" +
            "}";


             String answer = "";
             Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("sample_pres.ttl", "TTL");

             Query query = QueryFactory.create(stringQuery);
             try {
                  QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
                  ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                  while(results.hasNext()) {
                        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
                        Literal answerLiteral = soln.getLiteral("birthDate");
                        answer = answerLiteral.toString();

        }
    }

            catch(Exception ignore) {

    }


    this.answer = answer;
    return answer;
}
```

The line of code that is giving me issues is the FileManager.get().loadModel() line. Here is the Exception that I am getting:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.NotFoundException: Not found: sample_pres.ttl
```

So I am gathering that Android is not finding the file, although the file is in my Assets folder. I am assuming that I don't/cannot use the AssetManager since I am not attempting to include a FileInputStream. So I'm fairly stuck at this point. Here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

I added the assets folder under app/src/main in my project structure. I am relatively new to Android Studio and I know that in JavaFX from eclipse I could simply use the absolute path for the File in order to access it, and I know that this obviously will not work in Android Studio. I couldn't find one example however of loading a Turtle file from a local source in the Android project (my assets folder) and executing a query. Every example or question on this site appears to be in regards to running a query from an external endpoint over an internet connection. So This is partially why I am confused. I am not sure how to run the query from a Local source in Android studio and reference the Turtle file from my assets folder in order to avoid the com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.NotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The issue is that asset files in android studio cannot be read in android studio. They have to be converted to a FileOutputStream, even when working with .ttl files and reading them in turtle. Here is an example of the code:

```
 String filePath = context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "my_turtle.ttl";
    File destinationFile = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("sample_3.ttl");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length = 0;
    while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();



    Model model = null;

    model = FileManager.get().loadModel(filePath,"TTL");

    Query query = QueryFactory.create(stringQuery);

    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    while(results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
            Literal answerLiteral = soln.getLiteral("abstract");
            answer = answerLiteral.toString();
            System.out.println(answer);


        }



    if(!answer.equals("")){
        this.answer = answer;
        return answer;
    }
    else{
        return "I could not find an answer";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by just taking the `InputStream` provided by `AssetManager.open()` and passing that to the newer `RDFParser` API e.g.

```
InputStream inputStream = AssetManager.open("sample_3.ttl");
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
RDFParser.create().source(inputStream).lang(Lang.TTL).parse(model);
```

This avoids reading in and writing back out the file unnecessarily.

It does however require using the `jena-arq` library as well as using a recent version of Jena (you appear to be using some variant of Jena 2, you will need Jena 3.7 or later for the above to work)

Comment: I like this solution, but I’m not sure how to query this solution from via the sparql endpoint. And as you noted, an issue is that I’m using this solution in Android Studio with the Androjena library which is outdated, but the only library that I believe is compatible in Android Studio. If you have a similar solution that would work in Android studio I’d greatly appreciate it. As you know, there are memory issues with writing this file unnecessarily, but that’s the only way that I’ve been able to go about doing it so far.